# Single Char is treated as Two Char

Tags: csv, oracle11g, sql-loader

When using SQL Loader to upload a CSV file (generated from Excel) to Oracle Database, I have this error:

> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TBL01, column GENDER.
>
> ORA-12899: value too large for column "TST"."TBL01"."GENDER" (actual: 2, maximum: 1)

Please guide me through the correct way to code the control file.

**CSV File Content**

[image]

**Control File Content**

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
INFILE TBL01.csv 
INTO TABLE TBL01
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(ID, INITIALS, GENDER)
```

**TBL01 Structure**

```
Name   Null Type         
------ ---- ------------ 
ID          NUMBER       
INITIALS    VARCHAR2(30) 
GENDER      CHAR(1)
```

Comment: That is not your csv file content; that's the representation of the csv file as interpreted by Excel. You need to open it in a text editor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From discussion with @Multisync:

He/She suggest that (this is workable but many modification involved for my case):

> the easiest solution is to put comma after the last column in each line
>
> usually a csv line looks like: 1,3,4,5,6;
>
> in this case you can use FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' in your control file

At last i add another line in my control file, and problem solved because there is carriage return at the end of each csv line.

```
    LOAD DATA
    CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
    INFILE TBL01.csv 
    INTO TABLE TBL01
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    (ID, 
     INITIALS, 
     GENDER  TERMINATED BY '\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `GENDER` is `VARCHAR2(N)`, where `N` is a max length in bytes (by default). In this case you can alter your column type:

```
GENDER VARCHAR2(N CHAR)
```

to give the maximum length in characters instead of bytes.

Or you simply have a small `N` (the max allowed value is 4000 for table column size)

Comment: @MMultisync, the column is `GENDER CHAR(1)`. I tried to altered to `GENDER VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)` and it also return the same error message.

Comment: @noobie GENDER is for column C in your xls? and all the values in C have length <= 1?

Comment: @noobie Then CHAR(1 char) or VARCHAR2(1 char) should work fine. Maybe there are some special characters in column C?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is only one character in column C, not even blank spaces exist. But i tried alter GENDER to `VARCHAR2(2)`. It works and the length of GENDER is 2. Odd.

Comment: @noobie Try to measure length with LENGTH and then LENGTHC. If in both cases the length will 2 then there is a special symbol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65268/discussion-between-noobie-and-multisync).

Answer (score 0):

Try TRIM'ing to remove extraneous spaces if they exist, but I suspect the characterset may be an issue?  I don't have experience with that but if you are using a 2-byte characterset and trying to put it in one byte in the table maybe that is an issue?  Something to verify at any rate.  Make sure the database is using the same characterset you are specifying in the control file.

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
INFILE TBL01.csv 
INTO TABLE TBL01
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(ID, 
 INITIALS, 
 GENDER "TRIM(:GENDER)"
)
```